# Show that the range of matrix $A$ is perpendicular to null space of tranpose of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$R(A)$ is range of $A$ 
$N(A)$ is nullspace of $A$ 
$R(A^T)$ is range of $A^T$ 
$N(A^T)$ is nullspace of $A^T$

Suppose $y \in R(A)$ and $x \in N(A^T)$.

How would one go about showing that $x^Ty=0$ (aka $x$ is perpendicular to $y$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the definition of $R(A)$, there exists $z$ such that $y=Az$. Then note that $x^\top y = x^\top (Az) = (A^\top x)^\top z$.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=Az$,
$$ \langle x, y\rangle =\langle x, Az\rangle =\langle A^Tx,z\rangle=\langle 0,z\rangle =0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The range is the span of the columns.